# Undefined index: type in C:\wamp\www\submit.php on line 4

Tags: php, undefined

Hi I have problem with undefined index.
in google chrome and mozilla it shows the notice but everything works fine in explorer it doesnt work.
my PHP version is 5.3.5.

The code: HTML file

```
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
    <form action="submit.php" method="post" id="Form">
        <ol>
            <label for="number">number:</label>
            <input name="number" class="text" type="text" size="28"/>
            <div id="butt">
                <input type="hidden" style="width: 150px; border: 1px solid gray" value="addd" name="type" />
                <input type="submit" class="formbutton" value="add" />
            </div>
            <div id="error">&nbsp;</div>
        </ol>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

SUBMIT FILE submit.php

```
switch ($_POST['type']){
    case "register":
        register();
        break;
    case "login":
        login();
        break;
    default:
        die(msg(0, "error"));
}
```

The error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: type in C:\wamp\www\submit.php on line 4
```

I already have tried:

```
if (isset($_POST['type']))
 $type = $_POST['type'];
```

and many other suggestions found on other topics but it doesnt seem to be helping in this case

Comment: Why would you style a hidden input? And what's with the random `<ol>`? I don't see any `<li>`s...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undefined index: PHP variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840314/undefined-index-php-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an input named "type"? Try changing $_POST['type'] to $_POST['number'], if that is the data, you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're ending up inside `submit.php` by some other route than submitting the above form.

Try this:

```
switch (isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : NULL) {
```

Or the alternative, generally-to-be-avoided-but-probably-OK-here approach:

```
switch (@$_POST['type']) {
```

Comment: Tnks, this `switch (isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : NULL)` fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$_REQUEST['type'] = ( isset($_REQUEST['type']) ? $_REQUEST['type'] : '' )
```

Check if variable is set- if not, set it blank although I would be checking your form as to why the post field is not being set

Comment: Check if variable is set- if not, set it blank although I would be checking your form as to why the post field is not being set

Comment: Edit your answer and include your last comment in it - and while your at it - format your code !

Comment: @Lock you need to prefix the code with 4 space characters, iPhone or otherwise. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help.

Answer (score 0):

you can skip this error with this line

```
`ini_set("display_errors", "off");`
```

this error returns when you use session or array but there is an index is not explained yet,
to fix this you need to add null value or what ever you like if this index is not used yet.

Answer (score -1):

Your

```
<input type="hidden" style="width: 150px; border: 1px solid gray" value="addd" name="type"/>
```

Should have also `id="type"`.

**EDIT:**

BTW, just mentioned, this `input` is `hidden`. Maybe your `switch` should be based on another variable, for example `$_POST['number']` or other text field?

Comment: Was gonna say unless you're using java or Ajax or anything else apart from php, id is not relevant